# How to not escape validation message in the template?

Tags: django, validation

I have this piece of code in my models files:

```
sn = models.CharField(max_length=20, unique=True,
                          error_messages={'unique': 'This SN has already been created. <br/> Please <a href="/?sn=xxx">search it</a> instead'})
```

I would like to achieve two things:

1. Show the error message as HTML instead of text. I tried `mark_safe`, `safe` filter without luck - although the HTML is not escaped there is no effect of it (the message is wrapped around with ""):
   [image]
   Source:
   [image]
2. Instead of "xxx" in the URL provide the value entered by the user

My current solution is to check the error message in the template - if it's the unique error I manually add the URL information but this doesn't feel right...
Does anyone have a clean solution for this?

Answer (score 1):

Not escaping validation message:

```
from django.utils.html import mark_safe
sn = models.CharField(max_length=20, unique=True,
                      error_messages={'unique': mark_safe('This SN has already been created. <br/> Please <a href="/?sn=xxx">search it</a> instead')})
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not a good idea to use HTML in field's error_messages attribute.

Field's error_message should be general enough to be displayed in *any place* of your app where such error may occur. Your message is specific to some kind of *create item* form, so the best place to handle the error is during the validation of the corresponding field of that form.

You can create error notification dynamically during validation, so inserting value instead of placeholder "xxx" would be more natural (just don't forget to url-encode that value, or you'll have a security bug on your hands).